# React native seleccionar dos veces para que se carguen los valores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Primero gracias por ayudarme, espero tengan alguna solución ya que no se que más probar! Estoy realizando una app en react native y en un  para elegir el dia tengo éste código:

```
<DatePicker
    modal
    open={open}
    date={today}
    minimumDate={today}
    maximumDate={new Date("2023-5-30")}
    mode="date"
    locale="es"
    title={'Seleccione una fecha'}
    onConfirm={(date) => {
        setOpen(false)
        getAvailability()
        onAddDay(date)
    }}
    onCancel={() => {
    setOpen(false)
    }}
/>
```

en onConfirm ejecuto la funcion getAvailability que tiene que consultar horarios en ese dia y cargarlos a una variable pero mi problema es que a la primera que lo ejecuto no se cargan los valores y debo abrir el calendario y confirmar nuevamente para que ahí cargue los datos.

Alguien sabe porqué puede ser?

No se bien que más información brindar debido a que no tengo ni idea porque sucede ésto. Si alguien necesita más código lo proporcionare! Gracias!